# Type 'MvcApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController' does not have a default constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

I am super frustrated in setting up a clean Web Api with Unity Container to work. Please tell me what I am missing as I am tired of this error.

I have Visual Studio 2012, New MVC 4 Wep Api solution, Added MVC4 Unity NuGet package.

I have following code in a file:

```
public interface ITesting 
{
    string Test();
}
public class Testing : ITesting
{
    public string Test()
    {
          return "Test";
    }
}
```

I have following line in Bootstrap.cs

```
container.RegisterType<ITesting, Testing>();
```

In global.asx.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
      ........
      Bootstrapper.Initialise();
}
```

In Controller I have following code:

```
    ITesting c;

    public ValuesController(ITesting _c)
    { 
        c = _c; 
    }
    public string Get()
    {
        return c.Test();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you register the controller too?

Comment: From what I know, there are differences in dependency resolver between MVC and WEB API, You should try to use the Web API implementation not MVC implementation of Unity : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/

Comment: @Patrick if you are talking about registering controller with Unity then its not required. If registering means Route then it was wired. My goal of this effort to come with least amount of effort to introduce Unity in Web Api project. There is something trivial that I am missing and I experimented a lot but same error. Thanks

Comment: @Hendry Im trying this right now. Thanks

Comment: @Hendry Added that package. Added UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(); in Global.asax.cs per documentattion. Added container.RegisterType<ITesting, Testing>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager()); in UnityConfig.cs. Ran app, got exception at GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container); that "The type initializer for 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration' threw an exception." details `Attempt by method 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration..cctor()' to access field `System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2' failed.`

Comment: @Hendry it worked. Your package did the trick. I created a bare barebone web app **again** and built up. With this version, There were lesser functions to deal this time. So the steps are 1) create empty web mvc web api with Empty template 2) add Web Api Nuget 3) Add this Unity package 4) add 'UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();' in Global.asax.cs under AreaRegistration 5) Add 'container.RegisterType<ITest, Test>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());' in UnityConfig.cs under 'var container = new UnityContainer();'. THATS IT. App is ready for dependency injection using unity. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helped. To help other people in the future, I will post my comment earlier as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, there are differences in dependency resolver between MVC and WEB API, You should try to use the Web API implementation not MVC implementation of Unity : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/

Comment: Using Web Api implementation instead of MVC did the trick. Thanks Hendry